# Funcunit's open is causing trouble in online CI services such as Travis and CircleCI

Tags: plugins, travis-ci, qunit, funcunit, donejs

I have a donejs plugin (https://github.com/riescorp/donejs-typeahead) and I decided to use funcunit (http://funcunit.com/) to do the GUI interaction tests. Everything works fine on my computer, either running the test page (http://localhost:8080/test/test.html) or running `npm test` on the console.

The problem is that when running tests on CircleCI or Travis CI the tests won't pass. The error is something like **"xxxxx page not loaded in time!"** (see example below).

There is a simplified branch to show what's going on (https://github.com/riescorp/donejs-typeahead/tree/testing-open), you can clone it, then run `npm install` and `npm test` and you'll see that it works.

You can check the details of the error in CircleCI here:

- https://circleci.com/gh/riescorp/donejs-typeahead/tree/testing-open
- https://circleci.com/gh/riescorp/donejs-typeahead/74 (sample)

Travis generates the same error but it will fail as I'm testing both firefox and chrome (chrome not supported in travis)

Example error:

`1) QUnit "test/test.html" on Chrome 53.0.2785 / Linux 0.0.0: donejs-typeahead GUI Interaction DEBUG TESTS DEBUG 1 Page //../src/donejs-typeahead.html not loaded in time!:
     Error: Expected true but was false
      at Object.ok (http://localhost:3996/node_modules/steal-qunit/node_modules/qunitjs/qunit/qunit.js:2194:12)
      at Object.assertOK (http://localhost:3996/node_modules/funcunit/browser/adapters/qunit.js:12:10)
      at http://localhost:3996/node_modules/funcunit/browser/queue.js:168:27`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have Funcunit open new windows in an iframe by setting `frameMode: true`. This is what the [DoneJS](http://donejs.com/) app generator [sets up](https://github.com/donejs/generator-donejs/blob/master/app/templates/src/test.html#L2).

Comment: Adding `frameMode: true` helped. The test were still not passing (`waiting for size on #debug-me, actual value: 1`) so I had to change the way to detect the results instead of using `.visible()` now I use `.exists().then()`

Comment: This happens in older versions of Firefox and Chrome only, but my guess is that a hidden object on those versions is implemented by reducing the size.